# Decompile C#, xaml and wpf application

Tags: decompile, c#

I saw the image of an app and I want to use it's source code but when using some decompiler I get over 500 errors. How do I use the code there are two files? I want to decompile the installer and the app itself.

- Link to installer file(not decompiled):
  [Comet Space Designer](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ivxcnne4whhnhqu/Comet_Space_Designer.exe/file)
- Link to source code:
  [Comet Source code](https://www.mediafire.com/file/eh5zw4scvmo75tv/Comet-SrcCode.zip/file)
- Link to the app (not installer and not decompiled): [Comet Copy2](https://www.mediafire.com/file/733i3xucikqdjud/Comet_-Copy%25282%2529.zip/file)

I know the installer but I don't know how to decompile the app itself.
I used :
just decompile,
.Net Reflector,
dnspy,
dotpeek,
ilspy.